# Message order in Gmail boxes

Tags: gmail-imap, imaplib

I wrote a simple script in python using imaplib to download gmail messages from a given box (or a label which behaves like a box).  Since some boxes contain very large number of messages, my script allows to download only those numered within an interval like 100-200, so that I can resume downloading as some later time.

My question is whether it is guaranteed that the message order within the box as provided by IMAP is always the same (chronological order).  My tests seem to support this conclusion by I would like to be sure.

-- tsf

Answer (score 0):

The [IMAP RFC states](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-2.3.1.1):

> Unique identifiers are assigned in a strictly ascending fashion in the
> mailbox; as each message is added to the mailbox it is assigned a
> higher UID than the message(s) which were added previously.